# Ruby on rails fatal error (failed password authentification for user ****)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

When i tried to run my local server rails gave me this problem:

```
ActiveRecord :: ConnectionNotEstablished: FATAL: failed password authentication for user "Blog"

Caused by:
PG :: ConnectionBad: FATAL: failed authentication with password for user "Blog"
```

But my password was correct and also my username.

HERE MY YAML FILE

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode

development:
  <<: *default
  database: Blog_development
  encoding: UTF-8
  username: Blog
  password: Giungla
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test:
  <<: *default
  database: Blog_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: Blog_production
  username: Blog
  password: <%= ENV['BLOG_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

THE TRACE IN MY TERMINAL

```
** rails db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)   
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: FATALE:  autenticazione con password fallita per l'utente "Blog"
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:83:in `rescue in new_client'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block in perform'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: FATALE:  autenticazione con password fallita per l'utente "Blog"
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:58:in `new'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:58:in `connect'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:78:in `new_client'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:24:in `block in perform'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate**
```

HOW CAN I RESOLVE THIS? I'M NEW IN RAILS AND I'M TRYING TO LEARN IT BUT NOW I'M STUCK

Comment: Look in the database servers log file to see what error it reports.

Answer (score 1):

So, your database configuration is correctly being used as your error message mentions the username that it attempted to authenticate with. I don't think there's anything wrong with your database config in Rails, I think the problem may be with a mismatch on your Postgres config.

I would try to attempt to connect to the database with the Postgres CLI client or whatever GUI database client you prefer. Use the same credentials as you have in your Rails config and see if you can get the same error.

How did you create this user in your Postgres database? If you have the SQL statement that may be handy to provide for more detail.

Running `rails db:create` might be the first command to run to ensure that there's nothing associated with the migration that could complicate things. I would expect that you would get the same error message for that command.

Also, what Rails environment are you using for this command? (development or production for example). Note that the production database config uses the env var `BLOG_DATABASE_PASSWORD` that may not be set in your shell when you run the rails command. The easiest way to test this in one command is:

```
$ BLOG_DATABASE_PASSWORD=Giungla rails db:migrate
```

Of course, you would want your production database password to be different to your development database, this is just an example.

I hope something here helps you solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Login to the Postgresql Database,

psql

alter role blog with password 'secret';